# "The Rocking Horse Winner" Characterization

Tags: short-stories, character-analysis, d-h-lawrence

I'm trying to analyze the characters Basset, Oscar, Hester, and Paul in D.H. Lawrence's short story ["The Rocking Horse Winner"](http://www.classicshorts.com/stories/rockwinr.html), to know which ones are round characters and which ones are flat characters.

I know that when trying to distinguish between round and flat characters I have to look for depth. But in all fairness, I get confused whenever I try to analyze a character.

For example: I think Hester, Paul's mother, in this story is a flat character. She can be described by just two or three sentences. Is this correct? How about Oscar Cresswell?